# array of arrays of structures in C - declaration

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, declaration, variable-declaration

I defined a data structure as follows:

```
struct image{
unsigned int width, height;
unsigned char *data;
};
```

An array of structures as defined above would be something like:

```
struct image input[NR_FRAMES];
```

If I would like another array, let's say `streams`, that has as elements `streams[i]` arrays of structures as defined above, how would I declare it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef struct image Stream[NR_FRAMES];
Stream streams[NR_STREAMS];
```

or simply :

```
struct image streams[NR_STREAMS][NR_FRAMES]
```